# Options to write Win32 GUI applications?

Tags: winapi, programming-languages

As SO returns "4,476 search results for posts containing "win32 gui applications""... I'll have to ask a question that has probably been asked before but is lost in the midst of all those questions.

Currently, what are the options to write GUI applications for Win32, that have a big-enough following so that the environment offers enough and well-supported third-party tools?

I could come up with:

- C++
- Delphi, and possibly
- RealBasic (although the fact that it's originally a Macintosh tool could result in small but noticeable issues in look 'n feel).

Besides their relative lack of well-supported third-party tools, solutions like Python + wxWidgets, or [Power|Pure|Free]Basic aren't good options: The former has too many 1.0 widgets (couldn't find a business-grade grid, for instance), and the latter are procedural languages so requires writing apps like Petzold's book with the lower productivity it entails.

Are there other solutions available?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Sorry for not having been precise enough: Big tools like .Net and Java are not options. I'm looking for tools that can either build a whole EXE statically (eg. Delphi) or provide a light enough runtime (VBClassic).

Comment: Visual Basic, Visual Fortran. It quite depends on your business area. If `Win32` just means `running on Windows` probably you can use .NET language - e.g. C#. .NET is very powerful in GUI development.

Comment: Practically any language has a compiler + class library that allows you to write gui apps on Windows.  You'll have to go shopping yourself.

Comment: "relative lack of well-supported third-party tools" - have you actually looked at the Delphi/C++Builder third party community?

Comment: If you're going to be calling into Win32 directly then RealBasic probably isn't going to suit you. The RealBasic IDE, compiler, and runtime are supposed to abstract the OS away, so OS calls can be somewhat... involved, and quite difficult indeed if you need *real* threading or expect to be handling window messages, etc.

Comment: Also, until (and unless) RealBasic shifts to LLVM for its backend, RB apps on Windows and Linux are often *not* single-file executables anymore.

Comment: You got 4.5K results because you searched for a very vague question. SO is primary for specific questions that have specific answers, rather than "I prefer X", "but Y is better", etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to programming I would suggest C# as well if you are only looking to make this app for the Windows Platform however with tools like Mono it can be ported to OS X and Linux Platforms.

Windows has their own IDE just for this called Visual Studio Express C#
[Visual Studio's C#](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express)

As well as a version for C++ if you are wanting to say in that programming language.

The Mono project allows you to use C# in Linux and Mac as well as port the apps to iOS and Android 
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

You Can use C++ or You can even use the .net framework to develop your windows applications. .Net framework have lots of opensource contributed modules and paid modules and well as number of resources all over the internet to speed up the development compare to other options you have mentioned.

If you are going for a windows 32 gui application, I would prefer to go with .net framework, C++.

Java Swings also another best options which is platform independent as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Win32 spefically because I don't want to use the .Net framework for this.

Comment: You could try with C++, which I see as the better option from the available options.

Comment: But C++ is much less productive that eg. Basic or Python. Are there really no other options than the three I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) as a free alternative to Delphi. Potentially you will have a very high possibility to check its "write once, compile anywhere" motto if you later decide to port your Win32 application to Linux or MacOS. In ideal case it will just work, but in reality you would probably need some conditional defines sections.